# Trying to decode 128bit or 256 bit string?

Tags: decode, encode, encryption

the password string is some kind of like that

```
MTY5LTYtNjEtMjAxLTkwLTE3MS05My0yMDAtMTMxLTE5Mi01My0xNjItMC0yMjAtMTgxLTIyNg==
```

I tried base 64 encoder and it gives me:

```
169-6-61-201-90-171-93-200-131-192-53-162-0-220-181-226
```

Looks like encode by ASCII Code
I put the numbers on ASCII code list gives me :

```
©=ÉZ«]ÈƒÀ5¢Üµâ
```

But this not the password that i looked.
Does anyone know the solution.
I am not an expert sorry for bad explaining.

Comment: Are you asking us to help you break someone's security?  Cool.  How much does it pay?

Comment: Is it possible that it is hashed instead of encoded/encrypted? If so you can't get the original password back.

Comment: In hex they are e2b5dc00a235c083c85dab5ac93d06a9 or a9063dc95aab5dc883c035a200dcb5e2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string contains 16 numbergroups and each number is between 0 and 255. So it looks like 16 bytes. And 16 bytes / 128 bits is the size of an md5 hash. So that would be my guess.

While a crypto hash function can't be easily reversed, there are online rainbowtable services which can revert them for short or common inputs. But if the programmer who wrote it did it right (used a salt and many iterations) they won't help.

I'd split it in 16 numbers, than convert these to a byte array of size 16, and then hexencode them, since that's the form most programs will accept. Edit: See Kenny's comment
And then search for some website which allows search in rainbow tables. And pray...

Comment: ...meaning OP will never *probably* get the password back.

Comment: He might get it back if the programmer was incompetent.

Comment: No I am not breaking someone's security? I am just testing the password security system. If I can break this, anybody in the company can steal the password too. If it weak, we need to make stronger the password security system.

Comment: Doing it via code review is easier and more comprehensive than doing it this way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer CodeInChaos

Comment: What is the string after you convert a byte array of sizee 16.

Comment: Kenny did it for you. I didn't check his conversion, but it looks ok at first glance.

Comment: sorry I havent find the rainbow tables, whatever thans for your interest